AVFoundation: Export video with dynamic speeds for different portion of video
I am implementing dynamic speed adjustments in video using AVFoundation.
for example:- I have a video of 60 seconds of duration.
I wanted to apply different speed like
0 to 10s, speed will be from 1x to 5x,
speed will increase as per the duration changes.
func applyDynamicSpeedControl(to compositionTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack, using controlPoints: [SpeedControlPoint]) {
    guard controlPoints.count >= 2 else { return }  // Need at least two control points
    
    // Sort control points by time to ensure they're in the correct order
    let sortedControlPoints = controlPoints//.sorted { $0.time < $1.time }
    
    // Loop over each pair of control points and interpolate the speed between them
    for i in 0..<(sortedControlPoints.count - 1) {
        let startPoint = sortedControlPoints[i]
        let endPoint = sortedControlPoints[i + 1]
        let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: startPoint.time, duration: CMTimeSubtract(endPoint.time, startPoint.time))
        
        // Calculate the smooth transition of speed between the two points over small segments
        let numSegments = 100  // You can increase this for smoother transitions
        let segmentDuration = CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(timeRange.duration, multiplier: 1.0 / Double(numSegments))
        
        for j in 0..<numSegments {
            let t = Double(j) / Double(numSegments)  // Progress (0 to 1)
            let currentSpeed = startPoint.speed + (endPoint.speed - startPoint.speed) * t  // Linear interpolation
            let segmentStart = CMTimeAdd(timeRange.start, CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(segmentDuration, multiplier: Double(j)))
            let mappedDuration = CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(segmentDuration, multiplier: 1.0 / currentSpeed)
            
            let mappedTimeRange = CMTimeRange(start: segmentStart, duration: segmentDuration)
            
            // Apply the scaled time range to the composition track
            compositionTrack.scaleTimeRange(mappedTimeRange, toDuration: mappedDuration)
        }
    }
}

This is how I am using this method add time scaling for duration and speed changes but, don't get any luck. Video looks chunky and speed don't looks smooth while playing the composition.
